# Why does the button stay selected?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm doing a simple 2 button menu. Each button is a movie clip with 3 labels for the states "none" "selected" and "hover". smartBtn needs to be set to "selected" on enter frame. When cinemaBtn gets clicked, smartBtn should go to its "none" state. But I'm not sure why smartBtn keeps on being selected.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var smartBtn = menu_mc.smart_mc;
var cinemaBtn = menu_mc.cinema_mc;

smartBtn.buttonMode = true;
cinemaBtn.buttonMode = true;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EnterFrameHandler);
smartBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuSmartClick);
cinemaBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menuCinemaClick);

function EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
    smartBtn.gotoAndStop("selected");
}

function menuSmartClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    smartBtn.gotoAndStop("selected");
    smartBtn.buttonMode = false;

    cinemaBtn.gotoAndStop("none");
    cinemaBtn.buttonMode = true;
}

function menuCinemaClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    cinemaBtn.gotoAndStop("selected");
    cinemaBtn.buttonMode = false;

    smartBtn.gotoAndStop("none");
    smartBtn.buttonMode = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENTER_FRAME is fired at the begining of each frame, so smartBtn will be set to "selected" state every time even if you set it to "none" state.

Remove EnterFrameHandler call or add a test like this :

```
function EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
        if(cinemaBtn.currentFrameLabel != "selected")
            smartBtn.gotoAndStop("selected");
    }
```